# Project Scala + PHP

Tags: php, scala

does any one joined php project with Scala ? One of my projects at work is helpdesk written in php, Im still sometimes developing this project, but I would like do some features in Scala.
Wonder if its possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Quercus/Bianca](https://github.com/CleverCloud/Bianca).

It really works, I performed some selenium tests on a PHP application in a jetty container. PDO mysql use JDBC drivers (it's way faster).

You can call Java/Scala from PHP easily : http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#CallingJavaMethods , the runtime is faster than the standard PHP runtime and you can publish your app in a WAR (sometimes, it's better than just sources).

If you plan to industrialize some PHP apps, IMO it's a good start.

(Example : https://github.com/un-jon/Code-review-Quercus/tree/democode/helloworld)

Answer (score 2):

The only true **connections** between two different *programming languages* are the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) or the programming language bindings.

ABIs and programming language bindings are low-level conventions regarding how a function or class defined in C might be available within PHP for example.

---

Another **connection** between two different *applications* written in two different programming languages can be the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) which is a set of functions one application (or both) allows to be called via an [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

The exposed API can be accessed through some conventional form such as [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC), [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSDL) etc. and can only access those functions which the application's designer decided to share externally.

Comment: REST conceptually allows a storage-driven application to store and retrieve stuff for another application. It's a very simple RPC with procedures bound to HTTP methods which also adds constraints about what custom procedures are allowed to do (statelessness for example).

Comment: And since both PHP and Scala have implementations for the Java platform, you can use JVM bytecode as the ABI, which is much richer than C.

Comment: @jwinandy's answer is the best way to go for this if you're willing to change base platforms.